# Clean link between electromotive force and difference of potential: potential difference around a resistor or inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, voltage, conventions, electromagnetic-induction

I would like to clarify some aspects of EM that I never realized before: proper link between voltage in electric circuit and electromotive force.

### **Electrical vision of electric circuit:**

In almost all the sources, you see the following relationship in receptor convention:

The **potential difference** along an inductor is:

$$\Delta U=L \frac{d I}{d t}$$

The **potential difference** along a resistor:

$$\Delta U=R.I$$

### **EM vision of electrical circuits**

Calling $A$ and $B$ the starting and ending point of a coil, we actually have:

$$e=\int_A^B \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=- \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \iint \mathbf{B} . \mathbf{dS} = - \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}=-L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Thus, I would not say $\Delta U=L \frac{d I}{d t}$, but rather: $e_L = -L \frac{dI}{dt}$, $e_L$ being the electromotive force of the inductance.

**First question:**

Is it a "mistake" when we see $\Delta U=L \frac{d I}{d t}$ with $\Delta U$ being the electric potential ? Shouldn't we only say $e_L = -L \frac{dI}{dt}$ ? **Indeed, as we are not in electrostatics we don't have $e=-\Delta U$ here**...

---

Now, for the resistor we can derive the macroscopic Ohm law from microscopic one. We have:

$$\mathbf{j}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$$

We assume $j$ uniform, thus $I=j*A$ for simplicity, with $A$ being the section of the conductor. We find:

$$e_R = \int_C^D \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}  =\frac{1}{\sigma} \int_C^D  \mathbf{j} . \mathbf{dl}=\frac{L*I}{A*\sigma}=R*I$$

Where $R=\frac{L}{A*\sigma}$

**Second question:**

For the same reason, shouldn't we say, $e_R = R*I$ and not $\Delta U=R*I$ for a resistor ? The two expression will be equivalent in the static case but not in the electrodynamic one because of non conservation of the circulation of the electric field in this last case.

Note: I guess I miss a minus for the resistor because in the static case we have $e=-\Delta U$. I don't find the mistake at the moment but I guess it is an obvious one.

Comment: This is an excellent and non trivial question. Walter Lewin addresses it in his lectures about EM. I suggest you watch the following video from minute 35:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGQbA2jwkWI

and more specifically, he talks about the case in an inductor as you asked in this video from 5:45 to 13:45 : 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2micky_3uI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit]: I figured out that my explanation is consistent with:
from 5:45 to 13:45 : youtube.com/watch?v=t2micky_3uI, link suggested by @Ofek Gillon in the comment of the answer.

I will try to put a rigorous derivation of R.L circuit without using at all any results that comes from conservative fields. In practice I will never make use of the notion of electric potential which mainly makes sense for electrostatics because field is conservative. I will only work with electromotive forces.

[image]

I compute the electromotive force on the full circuit after having chosen an orientation as given in my image.

$$e_{tot}=\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} $$

The inductance is here to **model** the flux going to the full circuit. In presence of coils in the circuit, it will represent the flux going through those coils additionned to the flux going through the full circuit. Without coils in my circuit, it will represent the flux going through the full circuit.

In all case we thus have:

$$e_{tot}=-L \frac{dI}{dt} $$

Now, I need to compute $\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}$.

$$e_{tot}=\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=\int_{gen} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}+\int_R \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}$$

For the resistor:

Here, I have no right to use $V_A-V_B = RI$ because I work in electrodynamic and the potential is not well defined electrically (field non conservative). Thus I need to "rederive" Ohm's law in term of electromotive forces. I assume the microscopic Ohm's law holds: $\mathbf{j}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$, and $\mathbf{j}$ uniform on a section of resistor.
$$\int_R \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} = \int_A^B \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} = \frac{1}{\sigma} \int_A^B \mathbf{j}.\mathbf{dl}=\frac{L I}{A \sigma} = R*I$$
Where $R=\frac{L}{A \sigma}$

Allright, the Ohm's law takes the same shape in electrodynamics.

Now for the generator:

$$\int_{gen} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=-e_{gen}$$

Indeed, the electric field inside of the generator goes from + to - and is thus opposed to $\mathbf{dl}$.

In the end, I find:

$$-e_{gen}+R*I=-L \frac{dI}{dt} \Leftrightarrow e=R*I+L*\frac{dI}{dt}$$

Which is consistant with what we are supposed to have.

Remark:

Here we saw that the law for the resistor also holds in electrodynamic, it is the same for the capacitor, computing the e.f.m oriented from the +Q to -Q plate of a condensator we have as well $e_Q=\frac{Q}{C}$

Answer (score 0):

In your calculations, if the loop is made of ideal wire, then $e=0$.

You have to apply the path integral on an entire circuit, composed for example by an ideal inductor, a resistor, ideal wires, and a voltage generator.

[image]

Using Faraday's Law (as you can see, no electrostatics...), knowing that in wires (including inductor wires) the electric field is zero, one obtains:

$$\int_{\text{circuit}} \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{l}_0 \mathrm{d}l = V_{\text{gen}}-RI = -\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t} =-\frac{\partial (L I)}{\partial t}$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Why would the total electromotive force on the circuit be $0$ ? How do you obtain $V_{gen}-RI=-\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$ ? Just to make sure you get my misunderstanding: I know that here I will have $V=RI-L \frac{d I}{d t}$. What I don't get is why we say the difference in electric potential around an inductance is $U=L \frac{d I}{d t}$: for me it is in contradiction with the fact we integrate on a close loop: the difference in electric potential around the inductance must be $0$ using Maxwell laws

Comment: "we integrate on a close loop: the difference in electric potential around the inductance must be 0 using Maxwell laws": on a close loop the voltage is not zero in non-static problems (in such problems the potential function is not defined).

Comment: The electric potential is always defined. We have: $ \mathbf{E}=- \mathbf{\nabla}(V)-\partial_t \mathbf{A}$. On a close loop we only keep the vector potential part which may lead to non $0$ electromotive force.

Comment: Yes, the formula you wrote is general, ok. What I meant saying that “potential is not defined” was simply “the curl of E is not zero” (my imprecision, anyway, sorry). The Faraday law I used is the Maxwell equation about the curl of E, integrated over the circuit surface (which is a complicated surface that follows the loops of the inductor). So now, what is not clear to you?

Comment: My problem is that as I never realized before that we don't have in general $e=-\Delta U$, I feel like I don't know which "axioms" I can use to go to the result from an E.M point of view. Here you compute on the full circuit the circulation of $\mathbf{E}$. You have $\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} = \int_{gen} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} + \int_{L} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} + \int_{R} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}$. $\int_{gen} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} + \int_{L} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}+ \int_{R} \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=V_{gen}+\partial_t \Phi - RI$. How do you know the full circulation is $0$ ?

Comment: Also, here I used directly the fact $\int_R \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=-RI$. But how do we  know it in practice. The basic formula I always assumed is $\Delta U= RI$. But here we have $\int_R \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=-\Delta U - \partial_t \int \mathbf{A}.\mathbf{dl}$. How do we know that $\partial_t \int \mathbf{A}.\mathbf{dl}=0$ on a resistor ? (Again I am confused because from this question I feel like I don't know anymore what are the "axioms" and what I can deduce. Is the law for a resistor $\Delta U = R*I$, or $\int_R \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=-R*I$) ?

Comment: The axioms are the four Maxwell equations. Integrating on the circuit surface the E-curl equation you obtain the Faraday law. Then, the circulation is NOT zero, but is equal to the time-variation of the magnetic flux. For the expression of the field in the resistor you are using the medium equation $J=\sigma E$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104039/discussion-between-starbuck-and-nameless).

Comment: I edited my question with some of your remark and what still confuses me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104050/discussion-between-starbuck-and-nameless).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right; using $\Delta U$ when current isn't steady doesn't make sense. Every time I've seen Kirchoff's voltage law applied to AC circuits (for example, in Griffiths), it's been in terms of emf: $$\epsilon_0-RI-L\frac{dI}{dt}=0$$ I think the second and third terms would indeed be most correctly rewritten as $\epsilon_{R}$ and $\epsilon_{L}$.

To clear up why the TOTAL emf of the circuit is set equal to zero, besides saying "because Kirchoff said so": The magnetic flux through the circuit is negligible. The magnetic flux through the loops in the inductor, however, is obviously significant. This is why you get $\epsilon_{L}=-L\frac{dI}{dt}$. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why should the magnetic flux through the total circuit be $0$ ?

Comment: Also why is the emf through the resistor $-RI$. I have $+R*I$ when I start from microscopic Ohm's law (look at my derivation in my question). This also confuses me

Comment: The magnetic field induced by the inductor loops is parallel to the plane the circuit is on, and the magnetic field induced by the circuit itself is negligible (it's just one large loop). I'll edit my answer, since negligible does not mean it's EXACTLY zero.

Comment: The emf of the resistor works in the opposite direction of the battery's emf, so they are opposite signs. Writing RI+LdI/dt-e0 = 0 is equally valid. Purely up to convention. Integrating cw around the circuit gives the same answer as integrating ccw

Comment: Well for me "physically" the total flux is equal to the circulation of the electromotive force around the whole loop. This is why I think it is not that the variation of flux on all the circuit is 0. The variation of flux is equal to the one done by the coils + the one of the full circuit. We can neglect the second one if we want. But then it is really $\oint \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=-\frac{d \phi}{d t} = -L\frac{d I}{dt}$ if we neglect the variation of flux of the circuit itself

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the other answers, it is actually perfectly legitimate to treat the voltage across an inductor in an AC circuit as a voltage instead of an EMF *provided the assumptions of circuit theory are met*. The assumptions of circuit theory are as follows (see Nilsson and Riedel, Electric Circuits, ch 1):

1) there is no net charge on any circuit element, 
2) there is no magnetic coupling between circuit elements, and 
3) the circuit is small compared to the speed of light and the time scales of interest

Those assumptions are very powerful and allow treating a circuit as a bunch of connected “lumped elements” with no internal structure and no geometry (only topology).

One derivation is outlined in section 11.3 of the MIT online textbook http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/book.html

There it shows how the circuit theory assumptions are used to simplify Maxwell’s equations such that at the boundary of the lumped element you can treat it simply by the voltage and current at a discrete number of terminals on the boundary with regard to electrical power. The magnetic fields inside the boundary are unimportant as are the voltages on the boundary anywhere else besides the terminals.

So, although you may have an EMF inside the circuit element, as long as the assumptions of circuit theory are satisfied, it can be treated fully as a simple voltage anywhere outside the boundary of the lumped element, and in particular at the terminals.

Note, Walter Lewin’s famous anti-Kirchoff’s lecture is not a contradiction to my comments here. His approach is to explicitly violate the assumptions of circuit theory. Contrary to his assertions, there is nothing wrong with Kirchoff’s circuit laws provided the assumptions of circuit theory are met.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure it is in section 11.3 ? I went through this section and I dont see the part where they express what you said

Comment: @StarBuck yes, it is the subsection entitled “Poynting Power Density Related to Circuit Power Input”